# External pages redirecting back to wordpress

Tags: filesystem

So I've created a folder under my wordpress root directory containing simple vueJS html files and assets such that anyone can access them from a url like:

**Mywordpress.com/externalfolder**

My external folder however contains its own routes and url params so going to a url like **Mywordpress.com/externalfolder/about** should be handled in the page logic itself, entirely seperate from wordpress, but instead, wordpress redirects to 404.

How do i remove this behaviour and get the server to use whatever my external folder serves up, and remove wordpress from interfering with anything on the original /externalfolder/ path.

Comment: Move _external_ out of the dir for WP.  `...com/external/`  and `...com/wordpress/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1 - Move either WP or your vueJS into a separate folder severd from a new or sub domain,

2 - Adjust the default Wp `.htaccess` to ignore your `externalfolder` .

after

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

add

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/externalfolder/
```